# How to create a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have below dataframe. I want to create a simple histogram by sorting number of tweets numbers.

```
**Source**        **Number of Tweets**
Twitter for Android 59472
Twitter for iPhone  27244
Twitter Web Client  9239
Twitter Lite    6479
Twitter for iPad    1159
TweetCaster for Android 407
Twitter for Windows Phone   233
TweetDeck   219
Mobile Web (M2) 197
Twitter for Windows 134
Commun.it   121
Facebook    18
Media Studio    16
MeTweets for Windows Phone  14
```

Here is the code;

```
my_plot = data.sort(columns='Number of Tweets',ascending=False).plot(
                    kind='bar',legend=None,title="Tweet Numbers Per Source")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Source")
my_plot.set_ylabel("Tweet Numbers")
```

But I get the warning:

```
/home/bd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1:
    FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)
if __name__ == '__main__':`
```

Also, when I code:

```
my_plot.show()
```

I get below error message.

`AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: What conclusion do you draw from `sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)`?

Comment: Hi, can you extend your core more to include how do you import plotting modules?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I get histogram in this way. I also fixed FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....) part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly correct the error with histogram:
I assume that you use matplotlib library for your histogram and that you import your library like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then try to run this command at the end:

```
plt.show()
```

Instead of:

```
my_plot.show()
```

It's contraintuitive to use this plt.show method without referencing the particular object that contains your data.

Check [this link](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html) for an example histogram. They use numpy and matplotlib.
Next you want to use bar chart, not histogram. Histogram takes hundreds to thousands numbers and it sorts them to some number of columns, for example 5 of them. You have predefined columns that will be that high as their value. This can be shown using a bar chart. Check examples for bar chart [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/matplotlib-bar-chart/).

Comment: Please avoid assumptions. When you don't know, ask in a comment first. Then, if your assumption is true, post an answer.

Comment: Ok, I get histogram in this way. I also fixed FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....) part.

Comment: but I want to get the first 10 items to be shown in histogram. I added 'bins = 10' into  my_plot = data.sort(columns='Number of Tweets',ascending=False).plot(
                    kind='bar',legend=None,title="Tweet Numbers Per Source", bins = 10)  but I  get an error message.

Comment: @klutt I'm curious as to why you feel that way. Assumptions well-made can sometimes save an otherwise unanswerable question.

Comment: @jpaugh Huh? I said that you should not assume in an *answer*. Ask for clarifications in a *comment*. Then, when OP has clarified the question, you answer. Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) It says you should not answer questions that are *are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.* Since nio had to assume stuff, the question was not clear enough.

Comment: @klutt I see. I always took that as advisory, since it says "Save yourself some frustration..." To be clear, rescuing a question is a 'heroic' act which is likely to be frustrating. I don't dispute that fact. Occasionally, it can be done in a way that helps future readers, though.

Comment: @Behzat now i see what you want to achieve, you want to use bar chart, not histogram. Histogram takes hundreds to thousands numbers and it sorts them to some number of columns, for example 5. You have predefined columns that will be that high as their value. This can be shown using bar chart.

Comment: I'm sorry for using an assumption. I tried to answer the question as a challenge. And to the question poster: It would be good for future if you asked next question with a small piece of code with imports and the important part (you did this just you stripped too much of code) or even simplifying your original code to form a small demonstration code and stated what libraries you use. And next, when you solve enough problems under one question you should create new one so you don't modify question indefinitely. And if you find some answer valuable you can accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: It's true you shouldn't answer a question if you have to make _big_ assumptions. However, in this case I think assuming the use of matplotlib (especially as the code had things like `.set_xlabel()`) was a safe assumption

Comment: @nio I applied bar chart and that's what I need exactly. Thank you Nio. But plot does not show x line items seperately, items' letters are mixed each other. Do you know how can I change the size or type of the letters in x line  ?

Comment: Hi, I don't have experience with this alignment problem, you should create a new question with example picture and small working code. Maybe someone knows how to fix it. Google for matplotlib tick label alignment.